# HTML table question regarding <td> splitting

Tags: html, html-table

This html table code is quite confusing to me. So I made two table cells inside another cell. But the question is why do I have to put the first division cell `<td>Jupiter</td>` within the first row and have to make the second row for my second division cell Saturn in order to stack them vertically? why can't I put Saturn inside the first row all together with Jupiter?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Jovian Planets</th>
    <td rowspan="2">Gas Giants</td>
    <td class="names">Jupiter</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="names">Saturn</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please explain in detail what the issue is. Thanks.

Comment: This is just the basic way that HTML `<table>s` function, at least out of the box.  `<tr>` stands for table-row, and so everything within a `<tr>` tag goes into the same row.  It looks like you are trying to build a table column-by-column, instead of row-by-row, which is just fundamentally not how it works.  I don't really know a good `<table>`-based workaround for this problem, but if you want to build columns/stacks of things, CSS Grid and Flexbox can both make this pretty easy.  What you use depends on your eventual goal though.